# Excel 2013 Power Pivot RemoteApp - limited by 4 concurrent users?

Tags: remoteapp, microsoft-excel, concurrency, powerpivot

We're trying to use Excel 2013 (64bit) + Power Pivot via RemoteApp. The problem we're having is basically the same as described [this TechNet thread](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/fdd1450f-5673-446f-ae18-6b44c668d823/excel-2013-powerpivot-windows-2008-r2-x64-terminal-server-max-4-users?forum=winserverTS). 4 concurrent users have no problem using Power Pivot, the 5th person gets this error: "Couldn't load the data model. This may be because the data model in this work map is damaged".

Any idea?

EDIT: Got an answer in the TechNet thread, that 32-bit office helped. Will try that and post results here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can confirm that using 32-bit Excel indeed solves the issue. No idea why the problem with the 64-bit version though.